# when i try to posting data from angular to server Why data is not Bindig at serverside

Tags: angularjs

Here im trying to posting data from angular to api server in angular side it maping properly but wht it not binding at serverside
 Emplyeectr.js

**Emplyeeserve.js**

```
   this.saveEmp = function (savingdata) {
        var sersave = $http({
            url: Privateurl2+'SaveEmpData',
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: JSON.stringify(savingdata),
            content: { 'content-type': 'application/Json' }
        })
        return sersave;
    }
```

**Emplyeectrl.js**

```
$scope.SaveDb = function (user) {

    if ($scope.Validate = "UpdateEmpDetails")
        $scope.Submitted = true;
    if ($scope.isFormValid) {
        var savingdata = {
            EmpName: $scope.User.EmpName,
            Gen_Name: $scope.User.Gen_Name,
            Email: $scope.User.Email,
            Psw: $scope.User.Psw,
            Cnt_Id: $scope.User.Cnt_Id,
            Sts_Id: $scope.User.Sts_Id,
            City_Id: $scope.User.City_Id,

        }
        var saving = Myservice.saveEmp(savingdata);
        saving.then(function () {

        })
    }
}
```

When i trace it from Fiddler it passing data as

```
{"EmpName":"Aa1.com","Gen_Name":"Male","Email":"Das@gmail","Psw":"1478","Cnt_Id":2,"Sts_Id":4,"City_Id":7}
```

Answer (score 2):

The content you are posting is not in the correct format. You are trying to post JSON but telling the server it's form data.

You should change

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
```

to

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
```

you should probably remove the `content` property as it's not in the AngularJS docs and probably a little mis-leading.

Comment: Error as  Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: [Route("SaveEmpData")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void SaveEmp(Employee ee)
        {


        }

Comment: when i try to posting its from POSTMAN Its Binding

Comment: Have you looked at any differences between the fiddler traces between AngularJS and Postman?

Comment: yes when i posted that data in Bulk edit its not Binding  from PostMan